Black-haired androgynous Victorian swordswoman duels a middle-aged man in palace and ruins, blocks a sword with a rock, on Cartoon Network
I was watching (fantastic) The Steven Universe Rant by Robobuddies when I suddenly saw an amazing clip soundless clip featuring a black-haired androgynous woman duelling a middle-aged man on marble stairs inside a palace. 
Ten minutes later in the video, there was another scene of the same duel, this time with sound, where the pair is dueling on top of ruined bridge and the red-clad woman blocks the sword with a rock while delivering a fatal blow to the man with a pointy beard and I suddenly felt what StackOverflowers feel when they see freehand circles with drop shadows.
I tried searching for "a cartoon about victorian swordswoman that fights a guy with a pointed beard" and "Cartoon Network woman blocks sword with a rock" but to no effect.
Can anyone identify this cartoon series?
(Additional information that can be easily identified from the clips: aired on Cartoon Network, animation quality clearly indicating 21st century, possibly newer than 2005.)

That's not a woman, that is a guy.

That is Sym-Bionic Titan (2010-2011). You can see that here in this youtube video The episode you were watching looks to be "In the middle of the night" (or maybe that's the name of the song?)



I took a screen shot of the face, then did a google search and this is what I came up with. 
